# strange behavior of ps in debian 7.1

Tags: linux, debian, ps

Process exists:

```
antonshuvalov   21770   0.0  0.0  2432784    476 s003  R+   12:39AM   0:00.00 grep clusterize master
```

but if I try to execute

```
ps -eo pid,comm | grep "clusterize maste"
```

I get no pid

And if I try to execute

```
ps -eo pid,comm | grep "clusterize mast"
```

I get the pid!